# How to display my module in one of multiple website Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have two websites in Odoo.

Site 1: www.A.com

Site 2: www.B.fr

I created a module but I would like it to be visible only in website 2. But when I install it, it appears in both sites. I must then change the views manually in Odoo so that my view is visible on site 2.

I tried to put "website_id: 'B' in **manifest.py** but it doesn't work.

Where should I report please? I searched but I can't find a solution ...

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain how you changed manually the views?

Comment: @Kenly Go to views and here, change the name of the website that you want the view appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your view or template and test for the website id to add your content, for example:

```
<template id = "test" name="test" inherit_id="test.test_view" priority="16">
    <t t-if="website.id == 1">
        <!-- add or edit the content that you want-->
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the value of `website_id` field when you define the view or set its value by inheriting an existing view.

You will need the external id of website2(`website.website2`) and the external id of an existing view in case you need to use inheritance.

***Specify the value in the view definition:***

```
<record id="MODEL_view_TYPE" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">NAME</field>
    <field name="model">MODEL</field>
    <field name="website_id" ref="Website_External_Id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
```

***Inherit an existing view and specify the website_id field value:***

```
<record id="VIEW_External_ID" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="website_id" ref="Website_External_Id"/>
</record>
```